# Собирать getElementsByClassName в массив и передавать json по сабмиту формы аяксом

Tags: javascript, ajax, json

Есть popup с чат-ботом и один `input`. При открытии окна сразу имеется сообщение от бота, затем пользователь строит диалог. После каждого сабмита необходимо брать массив с сообщениями пользователя и отправлять json'ом массив, состоящий из всех сообщений.

На данный момент реализована возможность отправлять каждое сообщение на сервер в отдельности

**Пример кода:**

```
<div id="chatbot">
<div id="chatbot-message">
    <p>
        <span class="user">bot: </span>
        Здравствуйте! Как Вас зовут?
    </p>
    <br>
    <p class="from-user"><span class="user">Вы: </span>msg1</p><br>
    <p class="from-bot"><span class="user">bot: </span>bot msg</p><br>
    <p class="from-user"><span class="user">Вы: </span>msg2</p><br>
    <p class="from-bot"><span class="user">bot: </span>bot msg</p><br>
    <p class="from-user"><span class="user">Вы: </span>msg3</p><br>
    <p class="from-bot"><span class="user">bot: </span>bot msg</p></div>
<form action="ajax.php" method="post" id="chatform">
    <div class="input-group">
        <input id="chatbot-input" type="text" name="msg" class="form-control" placeholder="Введите сообщение..."
               autocomplete="off" required="">
        <div class="input-group-btn">
            <input onclick="AjaxFormRequest('chatform', 'ajax.php')" id="chatbot-submit" class="btn btn-default"
                   type="submit" value="">
        </div>
    </div><!-- .input-group -->
</form>
```

```
var messages = document.getElementsByClassName("from-user");

//for(var i=0; i < messages.length; i++) { var msgs = messages[i].innerHTML; }

//var msg1 = messages[0];
//var msg2 = messages[1].innerHTML;


function AjaxFormRequest(formData, url) {

  console.log(messages[0].innerHTML);
  //        console.log(msg1);
  //        console.log(msg2);

  jQuery.ajax({
    url: url,
    type: "POST",
    dataType: "html",
    data: jQuery("#" + formData).serialize(),
  });
}
```

Не судите строго, я только учусь. Заранее благодарен за советы.

Comment: жесть какая то, постоянно отправлять все сообщения. Кто вам сказал что так хорошо делать?

Comment: не говорят, что хорошо или плохо, сказали: "надо" :)

Comment: благодарю за ответ, пока сижу над задачей немного упростил разметку, так как передавать необходимо только сообщения пользователей, на данный момент сообщения от пользователя помещаются в отдельный span.message, что несколько упрощает поиск.
дошёл сейчас до следующего кода:

Comment: var messages = document.getElementsByClassName('message');
        var counting_messages = messages.length;
        var array_messages = [];
        var myJSON = [];
        for (var i = 0; i < counting_messages; i++) {
            array_messages[i] = (messages[i].innerHTML);
            myJSON[i] = JSON.stringify({сообщение : array_messages[i]});
        }
        console.log(myJSON);

Comment: Проверяй, поправил ответ

Comment: осталось научиться передавать такие массивы на сервер. загвоздка состоит в том, чтоб написать правильный ajax. сейчас имеет следующий вид:
jQuery.ajax({
            url: url,
            type: "POST",
            dataType: "html",
            data: $("#" + formData).serialize()
});
}
и передаёт при каждом сабмите только последнее сообщение, каким образом можно передавать формирующиеся массивы?

Comment: ну в `data` передавай `JSON.stringify(filteredMessages)`, а на сервере `JSON.parse(<пришедший параметр>)`. Вообще у вас кривые решения, и надо изначально хранить на клиенте весь массив с сообщениями, тогда парсить HTML не придется)

Comment: всё работает! огромная благодарность! единственный нюанс - отправляется весь массив кроме последнего сообщения, которые было в интпуте на момент сабмита

Comment: а ну да, дописывать надо тогда его в `filteredMessages` из инпута, перед отправкой.

Comment: Благодарю! Вы мне очень помогли!

Comment: Пожалуйста. Отмечайте ответ как верный

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Как пример, можно так:

```js
var messages = [].slice.call(document.getElementById('chatbot-message').querySelectorAll('.from-user'));

var filteredMessages = messages.map((msgBlock) => {
 return msgBlock.textContent.replace('Вы: ', '');
})

console.log(filteredMessages)
```

```html
<div id="chatbot">
<div id="chatbot-message">
    <p>
        <span class="user">bot: </span>
        Здравствуйте! Как Вас зовут?
    </p>
    <br>
    <p class="from-user"><span class="user">Вы: </span>msg1</p><br>
    <p class="from-bot"><span class="user">bot: </span>bot msg</p><br>
    <p class="from-user"><span class="user">Вы: </span>msg2</p><br>
    <p class="from-bot"><span class="user">bot: </span>bot msg</p><br>
    <p class="from-user"><span class="user">Вы: </span>msg3</p><br>
    <p class="from-bot"><span class="user">bot: </span>bot msg</p></div>
<form action="ajax.php" method="post" id="chatform">
    <div class="input-group">
        <input id="chatbot-input" type="text" name="msg" class="form-control" placeholder="Введите сообщение..."
               autocomplete="off" required="">
        <div class="input-group-btn">
            <input onclick="AjaxFormRequest('chatform', 'ajax.php')" id="chatbot-submit" class="btn btn-default"
                   type="submit" value="">
        </div>
    </div><!-- .input-group -->
</form>
```

Если сверстать первое обращение бота так же как остальные сообщения, будет массив всех сообщений.